# How do I remove a key if the key's date is N days older than todays date?

Tags: python, json

How do I remove a key if the key's date is N days older than todays date?

Let's say I want to remove all keys that are more than 2 days older than the current date (5-6-2020),

Original:

```
{
  "player": {
    "1-6-2020=>1591023427": "5.4M",
    "2-6-2020=>1591125091": "5.21M",
    "3-6-2020=>1590947416": "3.07M",
    "4-6-2020=>1591023427": "2.95M",
    "5-6-2020=>1591125091": "2.93M"
  },
  "player2": {
    "1-6-2020=>1591023427": "5.4M",
    "2-6-2020=>1591125091": "5.21M",
    "3-6-2020=>1590947416": "3.07M",
    "4-6-2020=>1591023427": "2.95M",
    "5-6-2020=>1591125091": "2.93M"
  }
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "player": {
    "3-6-2020=>1590947416": "3.07M",
    "4-6-2020=>1591023427": "2.95M",
    "5-6-2020=>1591125091": "2.93M"
  },
  "player2": {
    "3-6-2020=>1590947416": "3.07M",
    "4-6-2020=>1591023427": "2.95M",
    "5-6-2020=>1591125091": "2.93M"
  }
}
```

Comment: parse each key to date and calc diff between it and N

Comment: epoch date's looks like invalid, are those dummy values or actual values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to achieve the solution

1. extract the date from the dictionary (here I did it with the format with the datetime module)
2. filter out the days that are too far away (used python built in filter function for     this)
3. finally iterate over the players and apply this filter to the player's dictionary

```
def filter_days_wrapper(n):
    n_days_back = n
    def filter_last_days(item):
        current_date = date.today()
        entry_date = datetime.strptime(item[0].split("=>")[0], '%d-%m-%Y') 
        return current_date.day - entry_date.day <= n_days_back and \
               current_date.month  == entry_date.month and \
               current_date.year == entry_date.year
    return filter_last_days
```

Then the call should be with the filter function to eliminate the days:

```
for player in players:
    # used 2 for example, players is your dictionary
    players[player] = dict(filter(filter_days_wrapper(2), players[player].items()))
```